# C - data not being added to the txt file

Tags: c, file, error-handling, save

I'm supposed to be creating a small client managing program for a private clinic (before you ask, yes this is college work) but I seem to have found 2 bugs that don't allow me to progress on this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

    struct DATA {
    int dia, mes, ano;
    };

     struct cliente {
     char pnome[15];
     char snome[15];
     char telefone[10]; 
     char bi[10];
     float peso, altura;        
     struct DATA data;
    };


int main () {                        


   FILE *c, *tempo; 

   int op, i;
   int stelemovel, sbi;
   char filename[15];
   struct cliente a;   


     printf("1 - procurar\n");
     printf("2 - inserir novo\n");
     printf("3 - gravar\n");
     printf("4 - sair\n");

            scanf("%d", &op);

        switch(op) {


         **(...)**


        case 2 :

            printf("novo cliente. Dados: \n");

    tempo = fopen("temp.txt", "a"); //opens a file to store the data on so I can copy it later, this was an attempt to correct a bug I will explain ahead

               printf("primeiro nome \n");
               scanf("%s", &a.pnome); //scan the first name
               fprintf(tempo, "%s", a.pnome); //print to tempo file

               printf("segundo nome \n");
               scanf("%s", &a.snome); //second name
                       fprintf(tempo, "%s", a.snome);// print

               printf("peso\n"); //you get the picture so far
               do{
               scanf("%f", &a.peso);
               } while (a.peso<1);
                       fprintf(tempo, "%.2f", a.peso);

               printf("altura\n");
               do{
               scanf("%f", &a.altura);
               } while (a.altura<1);
                        fprintf(tempo, "%.2f", a.altura);

                printf("por favor insira data nascimento (dia mes ano)\n");
                do {
                    printf("dia\n");
                    scanf("%d", &a.data.dia);
                    } while (a.data.dia<1 || a.data.dia>31);
                           fprintf(tempo, "%d", a.data.dia);

                do { 
                 printf("mes\n");
                 scanf("%d", &a.data.mes);
                }    while (a.data.mes<1 || a.data.mes>12);
                   fprintf(tempo, "%d", a.data.mes);

                do {
                    printf("ano\n");
                    scanf("%d", &a.data.ano);
                } while (a.data.ano<1);
                   fprintf(tempo, "%d", a.data.ano);

               printf("numero telefone\n");
               do {
               scanf("%s", &a.telefone); 
               } while (strlen(a.telefone)!=9);
                  fprintf(tempo, "%d", a.telefone);

               printf("numero BI\n");
               do {
                scanf("%s", &a.bi);
               } while (strlen(a.bi)!=9); 
                  fprintf(tempo, "%d", a.bi);

 /* printf("%s, %s\n %.2f, %.2f\n %d, %d, %d\n %s, %s\n", a.pnome, a.snome, a.peso, a.altura, a.data.dia, a.data.mes, a.data.ano, a.telefone, a.bi);   */
/*this was something I used to test out if the data was saving properly 
which is EXCEPT for the a.telefone and the a.bi, they're being printed together for some reason

*/
        return main();


        case 3 :
            printf("nome do ficheiro\n");
             scanf("%s", &filename);

             c = fopen(filename, "a");

             printf("%s, %s\n %.2f, %.2f\n %d, %d, %d\n %s, %s\n", a.pnome, a.snome, a.peso, a.altura, a.data.dia, a.data.mes, a.data.ano, a.telefone, a.bi);

             fprintf(c, "%s, %s\n %.2f, %.2f\n %d, %d, %d\n %s, %s\n", a.pnome, a.snome, a.peso, a.altura, a.data.dia, a.data.mes, a.data.ano, a.telefone, a.bi);

/*this part basically should copy all I scanned in case 2 and print it to a document but I can't seem to be able to write on the file. The file is created opened but there's never any content on it */
            return main();

         **(...)**     

 return 0;
}
```

[This is the bug I get when printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htKfq.png), a.bi gets printed normally next though which basically tells me the problem is on a.telefone but I can't seem to see it.

I'm writing this here because I'm really out of ideas, slightly saturated too and as you can probably guess I'm not exactly a pro on files. Thanks in advance for any help being provided though.
I'm sure the solution is probably simple but I can't seem to see it at this point...

**EDIT**

Now if ya guys can help me on why I'm not able to print the stuff I scan to a file this matter can be considered closed.

**EDIT 2**

Ok seems like it's printing to a file but it's not separating the words through commas.

Comment: You shouldn't post parts of your question as an image especially since in this case the you're taking a screenshot of text. Put the text on here instead.

Comment: the (...) is just parts of code that don't matter to the question, it's just to spare space so I omitted the other cases I'm not asking about... The "return main()" is what I use to repeat the case from the beginning, it was the simplest way I thought to restart the case.

Comment: Stop. Bean. Counting.    Unless you are on a RAM-restricted embedded controller, desist from declaring char buffers smaller than 128.  Just stop yourself writing anythng smaller than [128], , write as if it is a fundamental limit in the language.  If, at any time, you think it's an inappropriate size, double it.  If developers would double it and add the number they first thought of, there would be fewer SO posts.

Comment: Weenie buffers, eg. [9], [15], [10], are unworthy of the name.  If you are male, they will render you sterile and impotent, if female, ugly and barren.  To avoid social embarrassment, join the 128 club today!

Comment: in general, it is a very bad idea to be calling main() recursively.  Amongst other reasons, main() has  a very special set of parameters.  Suggest having main() call another function and that other function perform the recursion.

Comment: the posted code, even after commenting out the `**<...>**` lines, produces 11 warnings.  Most of them on the calls to `scanf()` and `fprintf()`.  A very good start would be: 1) fix all those warnings 2) close the `switch()` statement.  3) remove the recursion, use sub functions and loops instead.   When compiling, always enable all the warnings. then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` (

Comment: when calling `scanf()` with a '%s' format specifier, always use a max length modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer, to allow for `scanf()` automatically appending a NUL byte to the buffer.  Otherwise the user can easily overflow the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and leading to a seg fault event.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) please consistently indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'. Never use tabs for indenting.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is visible even with a variable width font.

Comment: in C, a reference to an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.

Comment: this line: `scanf("%s", &filename);` is looking to set the address of an address.  which will not cleanly compile.  Suggest: `if( 1 != scanf("%14s", filename) ) { // handle error and exit }`.   Similar considerations for: `scanf("%s", &a.telefone);` `scanf("%s", &a.bi);`

Comment: this line: `fprintf(tempo, "%d", a.bi);` is trying to write a binary integer value to the output file descriptor `tempo`.  But `a.bi` is defined as an array of char.

Comment: when calling `fprintf()` and the format string does not contain a `\n` at the end, then the line needs to be followed by `fflush( tempo );`

Comment: regarding this line: `fprintf(tempo, "%d", a.telefone);` when trying to output a character string, use the '%s' format specifier, not the '%d' format specifier.

Comment: regarding this line:  `} while (a.peso<1);`   Since the `peso` field is a `float`, why are you comparing it to an integer?   suggest: ` } while (a.peso<1.0f);`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is printing `telephone` and `bi` together is because you didn't leave enough space for the '\0' at the end of the string. Strings in C are null terminated. This also indicates your not sanitizing your inputs. Doing `scanf("%s", str);` is very dangerous and leads to buffer exploits. You should provide a width to it like `scanf("%8s", str);` or consider using something like `fgets()`.

Comment: I'll keep a note of that for future use... didn't know you could limit characters like that to be honest, never made a habit of it... I personally been preferring to use "gets" a lot lately, makes stuff quite simpler...

Comment: @Xiriko,  Strongly suggest making extensive use of the `man` pages either locally on your computer or on line.  Do this for each system function that the posted code calls.  Then you would have known about modifiers for the format specifiers (and a whole lot of other important details.)

Answer (score 0):

The telephone string:

```
char telefone[9];
```

Is too small to held the phone number you punched in plus the null tereminator of the string. Changing it to something larger as:

```
char telefone[16];
```

Will work. But the probllem here is that you **don't make any check on the input data** for buffer overflow.
Always check for max input.

Answer (score 0):

```
char telefone[9];
```

This buffer can hold a string of up to 8 characters, plus terminating `'\0'` as the 9th element. You are experiencing buffer overflow by writing `XXX XXX XXX` to it. Enlarge the buffer to at least 10 characters and always check the returned value of `scanf` in each call:

```
char telefone[10];
if (scanf("%s", &a.telefone) != 0)
     // handle error
```

Consider using fgets to avoid buffer overflow:

```
char buf[10];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

a major problem with the posted code is repeatedly calling `fopen()` with the same variable on a file that is already open.

Suggest calling `fclose()` before every new recursion AND before exiting the program.